# Date issue while export to excel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

```
protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Detail.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htm = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            Repeater repAllUsers = this.rptrRegistrationReport;
            repAllUsers.DataSource = objAdmin.Getregdetails(start, enddate, usrtype);
            repAllUsers.DataBind();
            repAllUsers.RenderControl(htm);
            Response.Write("<Table border='1'" + "cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' " +"style='font-size:12.0pt; '>");                
            Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
```

All data are export proper but only date column showing #####.How to show date in excel file.

Comment: Please provide more code on this issue - at least how do you add data to your excel. Looks like you date field could be saved as "generic" and will show integer value instead of date (try to make it wider in excel - you should see it).